# Input vs Output: Job completed successfully, but some output files are missing

Tags: snakemake

My pipeline is failing I believe due to a conflict between the expected out put of rule all vs the actual final output.  I believe snakemake is waiting for the file `kma/{sample}` without an extension to appear instead it is getting a directory that has `multiext("kma/{sample}", ".res", ".aln", ".fsa", ".gz")` and I am having trouble getting them to play well.

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("kma/{sample}", sample = config["samples"])
        #multiext("kma/{sample}", ".res", ".aln", ".fsa", ".gz", sample = config["samples"])

rule seqtk_qualtiy_filter:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: "S5_Raw/" + config["samples"][wildcards.sample]
    output:
        temp("qtrim/{sample}.qtrim.fq")
    shell:
        "seqtk trimfq -b 0.01 {input} > {output}"

rule seqtk_clip:
    input:
        "qtrim/{sample}.qtrim.fq"
    output:
        temp("clip/{sample}.clip.fq")
    shell:
        "seqtk trimfq -b20 -L 350 {input} > {output}"

rule bbnorm:
    input:
        "clip/{sample}.clip.fq"
    output:
        "S5_processed/{sample}.norm.fq"
    shell:
        "bbnorm.sh in={input} out={output} target=100"

rule kma_map:
    input:
        "S5_processed/{sample}.norm.fq"
    params:
        ref = "ref/consensus.fasta"
    output:
        directory("kma/{sample}")
        #multiext("kma/{sample}", ".res", ".aln", ".fsa", ".gz")
    shell:
        "kma -i {input} -t_db {params.ref} -o {output}"
```

The error if you run it the way that kma would like to see the handling done

```
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 33 of /home/sean/Desktop/reo/antisera project/ReovirusS1AmpliconS5.smk:
Job completed successfully, but some output files are missing. Missing files after 5 seconds:
kma/BA8359-19
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
  File "/home/sean/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 544, in handle_job_success
  File "/home/sean/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 231, in handle_job_success
Shutting down, this might take some time.
```

I have tried increasing the latency time as well, however since the expected file is never actually created it doesn't matter how long you wait.

the error you receive if you using the `multiext` function

```
Error in rule kma_map:
    jobid: 11
    output: kma/BA8359-19.res, kma/BA8359-19.aln, kma/BA8359-19.fsa, kma/BA8359-19.frag.gz
    shell:
        kma -i S5_processed/BA8359-19.norm.fq -t_db ref/consensus.fasta -o kma/BA8359-19.res kma/BA8359-19.aln kma/BA8359-19.fsa kma/BA8359-19.frag.gz
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)

Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

This error happens, I believe, because snakemake lists all the file types in the `-o` flag and kma says no.

Comment: What do you mean by "job completed successfully", and "some output files are missing"?

Comment: it runs through the first sample and makes all the output files that `kma` creates and then fails because I think that it is looking for just the `{sample}` without a file extension and it times out because that file is never created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT 21SEP2020***

I have figured out the correct way to run this application.

first I need the `rule all` like this

```
KMA_OUTPUTS = [".res",".aln",".fsa",".frag.gz"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("kma/{sample}{ext}", sample = config["samples"], ext = KMA_OUTPUTS)
```

And then the rule for `kma` like this

```
rule kma_map:
    input:
        "S5_processed/{sample}.norm.fq"
    params:
        ref = "ref/consensus.fasta",
        prefix = "kma/{sample}"
    output:
        multiext("kma/{sample}", ".res", ".aln", ".fsa", ".frag.gz")
    shell:
        "kma -i {input} -t_db {params.ref} -o {params.prefix}"
```

by using the `parama.prefix` as the output file input I can get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an inconsistency between the input files in rule `all` and the output files in rule `kma_map`. Showing the error you get would help.

Anyway, the command `multiext("kma/{sample}", ".res", ".aln", ".fsa", ".gz", sample = config["samples"])` that you seem you have tried should not compile since multiext does not accept named arguments. Maybe what you want is this:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("kma/{sample}{ext}",  sample= config['samples'], ext= [".res", ".aln", ".fsa", ".gz"]),

rule kma_map:
    ...
    output:
        multiext("kma/{sample}", ".res", ".aln", ".fsa", ".gz")
    shell:
        "kmap ... {input} {output}"
```

Comment: thank you for advice, however this fails as well. The original error isn't really an error but I will post it in the original questions for all to see. This fails because snakemake tries to make all the of the outputs go into the output flag where kma is only expecting the "name" for the file not all 4 individual files.